# Python: what is the return type of this function?

Tags: python

```
def makekey(item, prog=prog):
    match = prog.match(item)
    if match:
        var, num = match.group(1,2)
        return num, var
    else:
        return 0, item
```

--
Is it an object or a list? Sorry, I am total newb

Comment: Also you can check which class an object belongs to, by using type(object).

Answer (score 0):

That type is called a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

Its like a list but it is immutable

Answer (score 0):

As Ashish pointed out, you can use the built-in [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function. So running your example:

```
import re

def main():
    prog = re.compile('^(.*)=([-+]?[0-9]+)')
    def makekey(item, prog=prog):
        match = prog.match(item)
        if match:
            var, num = match.groups()
            return int(num), var
        else:
            # Bad input -- pretend it's a var with value 0
            return 0, item

    item = "Test String"
    print type(makekey(item))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Returns:
`$ python sortingtest.py`
`<type 'tuple'>`